# iconv function on PHP

Tags: php, macos

I have a problem with converting a string (in Russian) to US-ASCII characters encoding on my Mac in PHP. However, on a Linux machine, it works fine.

```
iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
```

This is the code with an error in it.

I also have the same error on Windows machines. Can someone tell me where I should be looking?

Maybe it has something to do with the iconv library on the Mac.

The error is this - "Detected an illegal character in input string..."

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error message about iligal character

Comment: Are you sure it is utf-8 not cp1251 ?

Comment: Yes - I'm pretty sure about this, because I'm working on this project and on Linux machine and on Mac, and on linux machine I don't have this error.